# HTML Bootstrap placing an image into a column within row

Tags: html, css, image

I am using a container with a row construct to make a header. I would like for the leftmost column to have an image. However, whenever I add an image it gets added full sized. I would like it to be limited to the set size of that column.

This is my current HTML code:

```css
.logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="image-container">
          <center>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fb/76/5b/fb765b8752d50de50cfa15203f9a7acd.png" alt="test" class="logo">
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <h2><center>TEST HEADER</center></h2>      
        <h4><center>TEST SUBTEXT</center></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <center>wowow</center>
     </div>

   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding the in my CSS file but it did not change anything.

How can I have it such that the image follows the set size of the container?

Comment: try changing the column you are placing it in. is `col-xs-1` 50% width of `.row`?

Comment: The [center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tag is deprecated. If you want center-aligned text, use the text-center class.

Comment: Syfer, how would I set the width to say 15% of the total screen width. The middle column to 70% and the rightmost column to another 15%.

Comment: It is possible share the total scenario somehow? I tried in my local PC with same code seems working fine. May have outer CSS effects on nested element or else.

Comment: That's the entirety of it lol. Maybe my approach is just wrong entirely. How can I get 3 columns left and right 15% of the screen each and with images. And then the center just text?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below css:

`.image-container .logo{
width:100%;
}`

Comment: The result is the same as the CSS I have in the question. It does not go to the size of the column. It just gets super small. I would like it to span the columns size.

Answer (score 0):

The image is taking the full size of the col-xs-1 column. Just it is taking padding from left and right which all col- classes have.

If you want to make image a little bigger, then define its height (or width any one ) in px.

like the below:

```
.image-container .logo {
width: 100px;
}
```